# How does the token for openai works and how can I use less tokens?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, openai-api, langchain

Hello beautiful people!

I'm currently trying to write my own "AI" with the help of OpenAI. I have followed [Langchain](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OZpmLgd5D_qmjTnL5AsD1_ZJDdb7LQZI?usp=sharing#scrollTo=-pHw5siewPNt) and managed to end up having this code:

```py
import os
import re

import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from transformers import GPT2TokenizerFast

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# Set up OpenAI API key and models
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'xxxxxx'


def get_documentation():
    zendesk_url = "https://test.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/articles.json"

    documentation = []

    while zendesk_url:
        # Make a GET request to the Zendesk API to fetch articles for the current page
        response = requests.get(
            zendesk_url,
            headers={
                "Authorization": f"Basic xxxx",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            })

        # Check if the request was successful
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response_json = response.json()
            # Loop through the articles on the current page
            for article in response_json["articles"]:
                # Extract the title and body of the article
                title = article['title']
                body = article['body']

                # Remove any HTML tags and formatting from the body
                body = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', body)

                # Remove all newline characters from the body
                body = body.replace('\n', ' ')

                # Replace non-breaking spaces with regular spaces
                body = body.replace('\xa0', ' ')

                # Append the title and body to the documentation list
                documentation.append((title, body))

            # Check if there are more pages of articles and update the zendesk_url variable if necessary
            next_page_url = response_json["next_page"]
            zendesk_url = next_page_url if next_page_url else None
        else:
            # If the request was not successful, raise an exception with the error message
            response.raise_for_status()

    return documentation


# Load the GPT2 tokenizer
tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("gpt2")
print(tokenizer)


# Define a function to count tokens
def count_tokens(text: str) -> int:
    return len(tokenizer.encode(text))


# Create a text splitter
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=512,
    chunk_overlap=24,
    length_function=count_tokens,
)

# Fetch and clean the documentation
documentation = get_documentation() # The len of documentation is 93

# Extract only the article bodies
article_bodies = [article_body for title, article_body in documentation]

# Split the article bodies into chunks
chunks = text_splitter.create_documents(article_bodies)

# Get embedding model
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

# Create vector database
db = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0.1), db.as_retriever())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')


chat_history = []
@bot.command()
async def ask(ctx, *, question):
    print(f"{ctx.author.name} asked: {question}")
    result = qa(
        {
            "question": question,
            "chat_history": chat_history
        }
    )
    chat_history.append((question, result['answer']))
    await ctx.send(result['answer'])


bot.run('xxxxxx')
```

What I do is that I connect to my zendesk, scrape all the documentation by calling get_documentation() and then use it for chunks. When I then call !ask question here then I should get an answer back. However by checking my latest usage. It ends up using lots of tokens and I feel like it might be too much and could need some explanation or if there is anything I could even improve?

[image: Usage]

I know that when I start the script, it usually ends up by having around 46,179 prompt but I don't really understand why I pay without even started to ask a question. How can I improve it to use less tokens?

Expected:

To use less tokens/use tokens when I ask a prompt

Actual:

Uses 40k+ tokens everytime I start.

Comment: I don't know about the OpenAI API, but if I understand the problem right, you're using some OpenAI automation/enhancement tool which uses additional prompts, and you're doing this before a user uses the command. If this is the case, you can use a variable to initialize it only when the first command is sent, in `async def ask(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/prompt-engineering/tokens):

> Tokenization is the process of splitting the input and output texts
> into smaller units that can be processed by the LLM AI models. Tokens
> can be words, characters, subwords, or symbols, depending on the type
> and the size of the model. Tokenization can help the model to handle
> different languages, vocabularies, and formats, and to reduce the
> computational and memory costs. Tokenization can also affect the
> quality and the diversity of the generated texts, by influencing the
> meaning and the context of the tokens. Tokenization can be done using
> different methods, such as rule-based, statistical, or neural,
> depending on the complexity and the variability of the texts.

usage of tokens basically depends on input and output length, and model configuration. even a single punctuation can be classified as a token by the model. you can test the token usage at [enter link description here](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer)

[image]

In the above example, "," and "." counted as a token. in order to reduce token usage

- Keep prompts consice and precise. avoid using repetition, unnecessary punctuation and whitespaces, and special characters.
- Limit output length. In langchain you pass `max_tokens` named parameter.  The longer outputs require more tokens to generate. When you set a limit on the output length using the `max_tokens` parameter, the model will stop generating text once it reaches that token limit.
- As LLM updated to new version, that means it learnt more so the more LLM knows less token it uses. For example, `gpt-3.5-turbo` is a more token-efficient version of `GPT-3`.